# Account Lockout Policy in AWS as per PCI-DSS Requirement 8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, pci-compliance

Is there a way to enforce lockout on login attempt failure in AWS as per PCI-DSS 8.1.6? Currently, there isn't an option for this in the AWS Identity & Access Management console. I tried to implement it using AWS Simple AD Group Policies but accounts never lock. Is there any work around for the same in AWS?

Comment: Are you trying to lockout an IAM user after failed login attempts, or trying to lock out an LDAP user in Simple AD after failed login attempts?

Comment: I am trying to lockout an IAM user using AWS directory service.

Comment: I think IAM users are distinct from Directory Service users.

Comment: I created a user account in Simple AD to access AWS applications. I assigned IAM role to it. So its able to access the AWS console but it doesn't lock on login attempt failure. I have used Group Policy Object to set the policies for account lockout.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No. I wasn't able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a way in AWS IAM besides using an external identity provider or directory service.

The best way to resolve this PCI requirement for AWS is to require multi-factor authentication. MFA for all accounts and document MFA as a compensating control for requirements 8.1.6 and 8.1.7. The goal of those requirements is to limit repeated access attempts, and MFA compensates for that.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect. You cannot use another control as a compensating control. MFA by itself is already a control. Source: currently going through our PCI Level 1 assessment with a QSA and CCW with MFA for 8.1.6 and 8.1.7 have been rejected as non compliant.

Comment: That's interesting, I went through a PCI assessment as well in 2017, and the QSA was ok with it. I am pretty sure its up to the QSA here. Can I ask how you are planning to address this so I can update the answer?

Comment: We've added a lambda that checks all CloudTrail logs being pushed to S3 (luckily we already had one to dynamically set object lock retention policies based on specific account IDs). If the action from cloudtrail includes sts:* or consoleLogin we trigger a low priority incident to PagerDuty. This way we are being notified of EVERY login into the CDE, based on our approach and limited access required this is sufficient as it goes above and beyond of the original intent of the control. It's not scalable though for large organisations to review each login.

Comment: And on that note, apparently PCI-DSS 4 will be a lot more cloud-friendly.